# V10 Map node and database configuration by environment

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I can't seem to find this in the docs.

If I have a flow with a Map node and that node has a database insert as one of its outputs, I can configure that just fine.  What I can't figure out is how to change the database target when I go from environment to environment (dev to test to production).  In v7 I could switch this with a property file and use the mqsibaroverride command but in v10, I no longer see the database instance name in the output of mqsireadbar.

Anyone know what the 'new' way to do this is?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/cm28825_.htm

I found it.  You have to use a JDBCProvider.  Apparently, you can't use ODBC anymore.